# How does BotFather link CallbackQueryHandler with MessageHandler?

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

### BotFather Case

BotFather uses inline keyboards a lot. Let's say I'm going to edit my bot. There are some options, for example: **Edit Name**, **Edit About**, **Edit Commands**...

Let's say I clicked **Edit About**. Now it sends me a text message says:

> OK. Send me the new 'About' text. People will see this text on the bot's profile page and it will be sent together with a link to your bot when they share it with someone.

When I sent an about text for my bot, BotFather must be connecting the incoming message with the **Edit About** in the background. How the `MessageHandler` knows what's coming? The message I'm sending might be related with **Edit Commands** maybe.

#### Related Screenshot

[image: Example from BotFather]

### My Case

I was curious about this, and to be honest I still lack of knowledge about all these. I can't say I'm expert. I generally check out [python-telegram-bot docs](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/index.html) and [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/) webpage itself to find out what can be done for my own specific problem.

I'm planning to make an inline keyboard which is related with making feedback. I will ask user to enter something and then bot will forward the message to another chat. Long story short, how my bot will expect an input for feedback?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost sureley using some sort of [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). `python-telegram-bot` offers the [`ConversationHandler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a2/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html) for such use cases. Also have a look at the [`conversationbot.py`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a2/examples.html#examples-conversationbot) example.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.